# Multiplayer game in Facebook

Tags: facebook, node.js, comet

I am working on a multiplayer game which will be a Facebook app. Doing some research, I found out that for server-side pushes I need comet which is best implemented in Node.js or Python.

But Facebook's API is only written in javascript and PHP. I know there are third party APIs, but I do not want to go with them. I can do all the Facebook code client-side in javascript I guess, but that will be a little difficult, especially when it is so easy to do in PHP.

According to me, my options are summarized as below

1. Leave server-side pushes and stick with periodic Ajax requests + PHP.
2. Stick with Node.js and leave PHP and do all FB programming in javascript (if that is even possible, which I think it is).
3. use server side pushes in Apache (which I heard is not a good way to go).
4. Go with a technology like Java with some comet support and FB API's. (I don't know Pyhton).
5. HTML5 has introduced server side updates as well ,maybe it can help. (haven't given it much thought though)

Which is the best way to go? I have good experience with Java, PHP, and javascript.

Comment: [How to implement COMET with PHP](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start)

Answer (score 2):

All comet is is a normal HTTP ajax request where the server intentionally delays the response if there are no results, and continues polling the data-source server-side until there are results or the request times out.  It is a good approximation of push technology if important events are fairly sparse (i.e. if there are frequently many seconds in a row where there are no updates).

I don't think PHP is a great language in general, but it should not be much harder to do comet (also known as long polling) in PHP than in Python etc.  So if you don't have any other reason not to use PHP, then go for it.  You should also be able to interact with Facebook's API from other languages like Python or Javascript/Node.js without too much trouble.

HTML5 has, among other things, web sockets, which are quite different from HTTP requests and which can have much better latency than long polling techniques, especially for very frequent updates.  Web socket data is closer to what you might imagine "push" technology means -- comet is really just an approximation of "push" implemented through a delayed pull.  Whether sockets or comet or just normal non-delayed ajax requests are best for your game depends entirely on the specifics of your game, and of your server resources.